# Java Constructor in class

Tags: java

I keep getting the error

> constructor product in class product cannot be applied to given types

In the  `super(name, price, barcode)` section.

Here is my code :

Product class:

```
public class Product {


    public String name;
    public float price;
    public int barCode;



  public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

     public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

     public int getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }
    public void setBarCode(int barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }



    public String tostring(){
        return (" Name: " +name+ ",  Price: " +price+ ", Barcode no: " +barCode);
    }

}
```

Chocolate class:

```
public class Chocolate extends Product{

    public Chocolate(String name, float price, int barcode) {
        super(name, price, barcode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Decs : Name :"+super.getName()+", price :"+super.getPrice()+", barcode : "+super.getBarCode();
    }
}
```

Whine class:

```
public class Whine  extends Product {

    public Whine(String name, float price, int barcode) {
        super(name, price, barcode);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Decs : Name :"+super.getName()+", price :"+super.getPrice()+", barcode : "+super.getBarCode();
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chocolate c1 = new Chocolate("abcd1", "c1", 23.7d, 2.3d);
        Chocolate c2 = new Chocolate("abcd2", "c2", 23d, 2.3d);
        Chocolate c3 = new Chocolate("abcd3", "c3", 23.2d, 2.3d);
        Chocolate c4 = new Chocolate("abcd4", "c4", 23.1d, 2.3d);

        Whine w1 =  new Whine("Whine1", "w1", 23.7d, 2.3d);
        Whine w2 =  new Whine("Whine2", "w2", 233.7d, 22.3d);

        System.out.println("C1"+c1);
        System.out.println("C2"+c2);
        System.out.println("C3"+c3);
        System.out.println("C4"+c4);

        System.out.println("W1"+w1);
        System.out.println("W2"+w2);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `super(name, price, barcode);` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: And always use `@Override` on overridden methods. It'll tell you something useful about `Product`.

Comment: What specifically is the question? Why you get the error? How to identify the issue? What part of the Java specs your problem pertains to?

Comment: Whine doesn't normally come with a barcode. I think you meant something else.

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Product` does not have the constructor you’re calling.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your constructor on your `Product` class:

```
Product(String name, float price, int barcode) {
    //add your code here
}
```

Because otherwise Java creates a default constructor like this:

```
Product() {
    //add your code here
}
```

And then you get your conflict because of parameter length on both constructors.

To solve it, you need to:

1. Create your own constructor as I wrote above

**OR**

2. Call `super()` to call the default Java constructor instead of `super(name, price, barcode)`.

And as @chrylis stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423308/java-constructor-in-class/34423396#comment56588300_34423308) you're overriding `tostring()` method, so you should add an `@Override` tag above it, so it's easier to read for you and others, as you did on your `Chocolate` class:

```
@Override
public String tostring(){
    return (" Name: " +name+ ",  Price: " +price+ ", Barcode no: " +barCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are calling in your sub classes `super(name, price, barcode);`. In java this tries to call the constructor of your parent class that excepts these three params, which doesn't exist.

You just need to use the default super constructor (`super()`) or add the constructor to Product (which is better):

```
public Product(String name, float price, int barcode) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.barcode = barcode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add appropriate constructor to you `Product` class and declare it (maybe) as an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Product {

/* ... your properties ... */

public Product(String name, float price, int barCode) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.barCode = barCode;
}

/* etc ... */
}
```

**But**, a better idea is to make it as an Interface:

```
public interface Product {
    String getName();
    BigDecimal getPrice();
    int getBarCode();
    /* etc */
}
```

---

```
public class Chocolate implements Product {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int barCode;

    public Chocolate(String name, BigDecimal price, int barCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }
}
```

---

**Then** you can talk about polymorphism.

```
public static class main(String args[]) {
    Product chocolate = new Chocolate("Neuhaus", new BigDecimal(7.38), 9785455);
}
```

Comment: now getting error in main method : cannot find symbol. symbol: class Chocolate

Comment: I made a mistake within class `Chocolate`. I've already edited my answer. It must be `public int getBarCode()` instead of `public String getBarCode()`

Comment: @Garcia1987 If you have new problem then ask new question (you can provide link to old question in it). But to be honest before you post new question you should first search for potential solutions on Stack Overflow or other sites. This way you could find posts like [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)